# How To copy a file in ant irrespective of its location

Tags: ant

I want to copy a jar file from ../source,but I am not sure where it exactly is,it can be anywhere in any subdirectory but it is there. I am writing this code

```
<target name="CopyingFromSource" depends="clean">
  <copy file="../source/org.springframework-spring-support-2.0.8.jar" todir="../result"/> 
</target>
```

but is showing me can't find `org.springframework-spring-support-2.0.8.jar` Can you please tell me how to copy it?

It is present anywhere either immediately in /source or in any subdirectory.

Comment: got it myself anyways thanks,just need to use it like this `<fileset dir="../source">
        <include name="**/org.springframework-spring-context-support-2.5.jar"/>
    </fileset>'

Answer (score 0):

Use copy task with nested fileset like that :

```
<project>
 <copy todir="../result">
  <fileset dir="/home/gilreb/temp" includes="**/org.springframework-spring-support-2.0.8.jar" id="foobar"/>
 </copy>
</project>
```

see [Ant manual copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) and [Ant manual fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) for turther details..
 i.e. if you need to copy the flat file only and not it's whole path you need to use :

```
<copy todir="../result" flatten="true">
...
</copy>
```